# How can I add a column with values from a list, iterating in a data frame over factor levels?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, iteration, tidyverse

I am struggling in performing and iterating the following operation in the R environment.

Given a data frame `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(1,
                 1:12,
                 groups = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3)))
df
```

and the list `list_group`:

```
list_group <- list(
  A = c("Jack","John","Joe"),
  B = c("Ed","Edd","Eddy"),
  C = c("Gianni","Franco","Ugo"),
  D = c("Bob","Rob","Frank"))
list_group
```

I would like to get the following result:

[image: Wanted result dataframe]

Thus, add the column `person` with the names in correspondence of the `df$groups` level. This requires to multiple the rows over the factor levels, but specifically with the corresponding names in the `list_group` (i.e., `df$groups` level "A" = "Jack","John","Joe"; `df$groups` level "B" = "Ed","Edd","Eddy"; etc.)

I went through the function of the [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/), in particular `dplyr`,`tidyr` and `purrr`, but I did not find specific functions for my problem.

Also, I tried to dig into the theory behind Iteration in R, mainly following the guide *[21 Iteration](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#introduction-14)*, but I did not succeed in that.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76429705/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` + `merge`:

```r
merge(df, stack(list_group), by.x = "groups", by.y = "ind")
```

Or the `dplyr` equivalent:

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(df, stack(list_group), by = c("groups" = "ind"), relationship = "many-to-many")
```

output

```r
#    groups X1 X1.12 values
# 1       A  1     1   Jack
# 2       A  1     1   John
# 3       A  1     1    Joe
# 4       A  1     2   Jack
# 5       A  1     2   John
# 6       A  1     2    Joe
# 7       A  1     3   Jack
# 8       A  1     3   John
# 9       A  1     3    Joe
# 10      B  1     4     Ed
# 11      B  1     4    Edd
# 12      B  1     4   Eddy
# 13      B  1     5     Ed
# 14      B  1     5    Edd
# 15      B  1     5   Eddy
# 16      B  1     6     Ed
# 17      B  1     6    Edd
# 18      B  1     6   Eddy
# 19      C  1     7 Gianni
# 20      C  1     7 Franco
# 21      C  1     7    Ugo
# 22      C  1     8 Gianni
# 23      C  1     8 Franco
# 24      C  1     8    Ugo
# 25      C  1     9 Gianni
# 26      C  1     9 Franco
# 27      C  1     9    Ugo
# 28      D  1    10    Bob
# 29      D  1    10    Rob
# 30      D  1    10  Frank
# 31      D  1    11    Bob
# 32      D  1    11    Rob
# 33      D  1    11  Frank
# 34      D  1    12    Bob
# 35      D  1    12    Rob
# 36      D  1    12  Frank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base `stack()` and then a tidy `full_join(multiple = "all")`:

```
df %>% full_join(
  y = list_group %>% stack(),
  by = join_by(groups == ind),
  multiple = "all"
)
```

Result:

```
   X1 X1.12 groups values
1   1     1      A   Jack
2   1     1      A   John
3   1     1      A    Joe
4   1     2      A   Jack
5   1     2      A   John
6   1     2      A    Joe
7   1     3      A   Jack
8   1     3      A   John
9   1     3      A    Joe
10  1     4      B     Ed
11  1     4      B    Edd
12  1     4      B   Eddy
13  1     5      B     Ed
14  1     5      B    Edd
15  1     5      B   Eddy
16  1     6      B     Ed
17  1     6      B    Edd
18  1     6      B   Eddy
19  1     7      C Gianni
20  1     7      C Franco
21  1     7      C    Ugo
22  1     8      C Gianni
23  1     8      C Franco
24  1     8      C    Ugo
25  1     9      C Gianni
26  1     9      C Franco
27  1     9      C    Ugo
28  1    10      D    Bob
29  1    10      D    Rob
30  1    10      D  Frank
31  1    11      D    Bob
32  1    11      D    Rob
33  1    11      D  Frank
34  1    12      D    Bob
35  1    12      D    Rob
36  1    12      D  Frank
```